# lodash find property in nested array not working

Tags: javascript, lodash

i have an array like so

```
sections: [
     {
        editing: false,
        id: 1234,
        rows: [
            {
               editing: false,
               id: 3435, 
               columns: [
                   {
                       id: 1535, 
                       elements: [
                           {
                              editing: true,
                              id: 4849
                           }
                       ]
                   }
               ]
            }
        ]
     },
]
```

and im trying to find any object with a property editing is true.

the following code works, but only for sections and rows, but for some reason its not finding the property in the elements array

this is the js, using lodash

```
return _(state.sections)
      .thru(function(coll) {
          return _.union(coll, _.map(coll, 'rows'));
      })
      .thru(function(coll2) {
          return _.union(coll2, _.map(coll2, 'columns'));
      })
      .thru(function(coll3) {
          return _.union(coll3, _.map(coll3, 'elements'));
      })
      .flatten()
      .find({ editing: true });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first `thru` the intermediate result of the chain is an array consisting of an object and an array:

```
[
    { id: 1234, .... },
    [ { id: 3435, ... } ]
]
```

To get what you want, replace the `map` calls with `flatMap` which would then returns this after the first  `thru`:

```
[
    { id: 1234, .... },
    { id: 3435, ... }
]
```

As there will be `undefined` returned in the intermediate results if the objects don't have `columns` or `elements`, you will need to use `compact` to remove these before performing the find:

```
return _(state.sections)
    .thru(function(coll) {
        return _.union(coll, _.flatMap(coll, 'rows'));
    })
    .thru(function(coll2) {
        return _.union(coll2, _.flatMap(coll2, 'columns'));
    })
    .thru(function(coll3) {
        return _.union(coll3, _.flatMap(coll3, 'elements'));
    })
    .compact()
    .find({ editing: true });
```

Comment: perfect, thanks alot, i totally forgot that map returns an array